# Python - loop over list of dictionaries to remove redundant data

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
>>> testd
{'0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2': 
[
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.783199', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.799144', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.819618', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:46.973626', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E19D8013635EE0533BFA020AFB7B', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:47.447108', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E19D8013635EE0533BFA020AFB7B', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:47.462248', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E19D8013635EE0533BFA020AFB7B', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}], 
'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102': 
[
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.432990', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.444645', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.456260', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:36.036600', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E2D1BB356397E0533BFA020AACC2', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:36.374838', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E2D1BB356397E0533BFA020AACC2', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:36.398159', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E2D1BB356397E0533BFA020AACC2', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}]
}
```

There is another dictionary which is used to do lookup in above dict based in key and 'ID' key in sub dictionaries. The lookup_dict looks like this:

```
>>> testld
{'0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3'}
```

What I want in result is this:

```
{'0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2': 
[{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.783199', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.799144', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'abc', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.819618', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2'}],
'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102': 
[{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.432990', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.444645', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}, 
{'USERNAME': 'newuser', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'CLASS': 'IR', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:04:35.456260', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8NEW5B78416375E0533BFA020AA0D3', 'VALUE': 3360119, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'VID': 'C4F0895E4A6211E637A6005056AA0102'}]
}
```

Result is testd dictionary only after some manipulation in the original one. Explanation is as below:

1. testd and testld dictionary keys are same (which is also value of VID of each sub dict under testd lists)
2. testld values are the value of ID key (in testd sub dicts) associated with testd dict. Now each testd list contains 6 dicts having same number of keys. 3 of them are having same ID value and another 3 with different one, one of the value of ID matches with the value of testld dict. I need to remove 3 such dicts whose ID value doesn't match with testld dict (for that VID only)

The code I have created to achieve this is as below:

```
>>> for key, value in testd.iteritems():
...     for d in value:
...         if testld[key] != d['ID']:
...             testd[key].remove(dict)
```

My code is not working as expected, instead of removing 3 dictionaries, it's actually removing 1 only, not sure why!

Comment: avoid using `dict`. It is a reserved word in `python` for a `dictionary` object

Comment: so you want to modify the `testd` dictionary in place? Not create a new one with the selected items, right?

Comment: Why not give a good description of the results you want, rather than making us figure it out from a lengthy example?

Comment: @m_callens thanks for suggestion, have edited.

Comment: @RoryDaulton updated the description with the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it by doing this

```
        for key, value in testd.iteritems():
        for items in value:
            for v in items.itervalues():
                if testld[key] != v:
                    try:
                        value.remove(items)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You now have fast lookup by `VID`. What you want is lookup by `VID` and then `ID` which implies double nesting.

You can do it using one more nesting of the existing mapping:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> by_vid_by_id = dict(testd)
>>> for key, value in by_vid_by_id.items():
...     new_value = defaultdict(list)
...     by_vid_by_id[key] = new_value
...     for d in value:
...         new_value[d['ID']].append(d)
...
```

Usage example:

```
>>> by_vid_by_id['0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2']['37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47']
[
    {'USERNAME': 'abc', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.783199', 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'CLASS': 'IR'},
    {'USERNAME': 'abc', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.799144', 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'RQ GEN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'CLASS': 'IR'},
    {'USERNAME': 'abc', 'CREATED': '15/07/2016 08:13:45.819618', 'VID': '0CD7D6FE4A6411E61693005056AA00F2', 'VALUE': 3361231, 'TRANSACTION_TYPE': 'Elec', 'STATE': 'SN', 'REPORT_TYPE': 'RT', 'REPORT': 'NEW', 'MESSAGE_TYPE': None, 'ID': '37A8E019BB90637BE0533BFA020A8A47', 'MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER': 1, 'TRANSACTION_MODE': 'New', 'CLASS': 'IR'}]
>>>
```

I used `defaultdict` for convenience, but the point is replacing the list values with map values in your existing dictionary for fast lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new dictionary you can try this

```
newd = {}
for key,value in testd.iteritems():
    newd[key] = [val for val in value if val['ID'] == testld[key]]
```

It'll throw a KeyError if you have a key in testd that isn't in testld, but that seems like something that shouldn't be happening.